# Changing values in sql table with scrip

Tags: sql

I would like to write a sql script that will select two columns and change all of the results in another column in the table.

```
Columns
districtoid - (int, null)
product_code - (int, null)
depletion_rate_ton - (numeric(12,2), null)
```

What I've got so far...

```
select * from lrm_sot.dbo.vt_prd_depletion_rate
Where districtoid =430 And product_code = 1
```

I don't know how to write in sql, "change all the values in column depletion_rate_ton from 4.39 to 5.00."

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update the values in the table you need to update :

```
update 
lrm_sot.dbo.vt_prd_depletion_rate
set depletion_rate_ton = 5.0
Where districtoid =430 
  And product_code = 1
  and depletion_rate_ton = 4.39
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mention which database you are using. Below query might solve your problem.

```
update lrm_sot.dbo.vt_prd_depletion_rate
       set depletion_rate_ton =5.00
Where districtoid =430 
And product_code = 1 
and depletion_rate_ton =4.39
```

Comment: You are most welcome. It would be highly appreciated if you accept the answer by clicking green check. So that this question can be marked as answered.